# Replace not working in python

Tags: python

While trying basic python scripting  in eclipse IDE, I am encountering problem:
I just tried a simple code, which I found online:

```
var = 'hello , world'
print "%s" % var
var.strip(',')
print "%s" % var
```

The result i am getting is

```
hello , world
hello , world
```

Also i tried with replace command, but the result remain unchanged

```
var = 'hello , world'
print "%s" % var
var.replace(',', '')
print "%s" % var
```

The result obtained is

```
hello , world
hello , world
```

I could not figure out were I am making mistake.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, strings are immutable, change:

```
var.replace(',', '')
```

to

```
var = var.replace(',', '')
```

Comment: Stack overflow should have a "someone else is also editing/answering this question" feature. We both made the same question edits and posted the same answer within seconds of each other.

Answer (score 0):

Strings in Python are immutable. That means any methods that operate on them *don't change the value*, they *return a new value*.

What you need is

```
var = 'hello , world'
print "%s" % var
var = var.replace(',') # Replace the variable.
print "%s" % var
```

Also, `print "%s" % var` is redundant. You can just use `print var`.